# how to use NewtonSoft.json in MS build task?

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a build task, in which I want to do some json serialization/deserialization using newtonsoft.json as follows:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="ReplaceFileText" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <TargetFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <SourceFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />

      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />

      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[

            string sourceJsonString = File.ReadAllText(SourceFilename);
            string targetJsonString = File.ReadAllText(TargetFilename);

            dynamic sourceJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sourceJsonString);
            dynamic targetJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(targetJsonString);

            targetJson.firstProperty = sourceJson.firstProperty;
            targetJson.secondProperty = sourceJson.secondProperty;


            targetJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(targetJson, Formatting.Indented);

            File.WriteAllText(targetFilename, targetJsonString);

          ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithStaging" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ReplaceFileText TargetFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json" SourceFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.Staging.json" />
  </Target>
```

The above code does not work as I am making use of NewtonSoft.Json in the above task which is not referenced in this build task.

How can I import or reference NewtonSoft.Json in my build task. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional, .NET Core 2.0 and the project is a WebApi application ?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Your answer did work. however I am having other build errors when I try to build the project. Can you try to run the above task and check the errors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I import or reference NewtonSoft.Json in my build task.

Since you are using Visual Studio 2017 Professional, .NET Core 2.0 and the project is a WebApi application, you will find below code snippet in the .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So the reference `NewtonSoft.Json` is added to the project. But we could not reference this in the task. Because task dlls cannot reference any packages - they are loaded into the running msbuild instance and will only be able to reference the dlls that are available to the hosting msbuild instance. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434564/how-to-access-package-references-within-a-task-for-dotnet-build) for detailed info.

As a workaround, you can try to reference the dll file from the packages folder directly:

```
    <Task>
        <Reference Include="$(NugetPackageRoot)\newtonsoft.json\10.0.3\lib\netstandard1.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">...working fine...</Code>
    </Task>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, however `$(NugetPackageRoot)` is better than `c:\users\<username>\.nuget\packages\ `  ...

Answer (score 6):

Got it working with the following:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="ReplaceFileText" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <TargetFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <SourceFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />
      <Reference Include="System.Runtime" />
      <Reference Include="System.Dynamic.Runtime" />
      <Reference Include="$(NugetPackageRoot)\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.ObjectModel.dll" />
      <Reference Include="$(NugetPackageRoot)\newtonsoft.json\10.0.3\lib\netstandard1.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
      <Reference Include="$(NugetPackageRoot)\system.runtime.serialization.primitives\4.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" />

      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
      <Using Namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" />
      <Using Namespace="Newtonsoft.Json.Linq" />

      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[

            string sourceJsonString = File.ReadAllText(SourceFilename);
            string targetJsonString = File.ReadAllText(TargetFilename);

            JObject sourceJsonObject = JObject.Parse(sourceJsonString);
            JObject targetJsonObject = JObject.Parse(targetJsonString);

            targetJsonObject["someProperty"] = sourceJsonObject["someProperty"];

            File.WriteAllText(TargetFilename, targetJsonObject.ToString());

          ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithDevelopment" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Development'" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ReplaceFileText TargetFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json" SourceFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.Development.json" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithStaging" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Staging'" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ReplaceFileText TargetFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json" SourceFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.Staging.json" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithProduction" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Production'" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ReplaceFileText TargetFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json" SourceFilename="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.Production.json" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your sharing. It could help other community members who get the same issues

Comment: You could also try using `$(NuGetPackageRoot)newtonsoft.json\10.0.3\…` so you don't need to hardcode the nuget path and make it work cross platform (CodeTaskFactory also works on mono's msbuild).